# Single inflection point theorem

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality, jensen-inequality

Let $f$ be a twice differentiable function on $\mathbb{R}$ with a single inflection point, let $S$ be a fixed real number and let $$g(x) = f(x) + (n-1)f(\frac{S-x}{n-1}).$$
If $x_1, x_2,...,x_n$ are real numbers such that $x_1+x_2+... +x_n=S$, then
$$\text{inf } g(x) \leq f(x_1) +f(x_2) +... +f(x_n) \leq \text{sup } g(x) $$

I found it in a book of algebraic inequalities... But the proof was not presented by the author... I tried to prove it, but could not proceed...

Any help on this will be appreciated...

Comment: That $f$ has one inflection point means that the slope of $f$ has a single extremum. It is either increasing up to the point, then decreasing, or vice versa. If $g$ is unbounded, then the inquality is trivial. If $g$ is bounded, then $f$ has parallel asymptotes at $\pm\infty$. Likely what you need to show is that there is some $i, j$ such that $g(x_i) \le \sum_k f(x_k) \le g(x_j)$.